# Storing hex values as integers

Tags: python, hex, python-docx

I am currently working with python docx and it requires hex values to format font color for example

```
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x70, 0xad, 0x47)
```

However I need to store the arguement for `RGBColor` in a variable, a dictionary to be exact however when you store a hex value in a variable it will format it to an int. example:

```
code = (0x70, 0xad, 0x47)

print(code)
```

returns: `(112, 173, 71)`

and storing it using the `hex()` function will format it to be a `str`.

```
code = (hex(0x70), hex(0xad), hex(0x47))

print(code)
```

returns: `('0x70', '0xad', '0x47')`

and the `RGBColor` operator will not accept strings, and I cannot re-format these strings back into an `int` because I get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x70'`

In summery how can I store a hex value such as `0x70, 0xad, 0x47` as an integer that I can then feed into the `RGBColor` opperator?

Comment: Hex values are just reformatted ints. Then you just need RGBColor(*code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(112, 173, 71)
```

produces the same result as:

```
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x70, 0xad, 0x47)
```

The `0x7f` format is just an alternate Python literal form for an `int` value. There is only one kind of `int`, just multiple ways of expressing the same value as a literal. See the Python docs on numeric literals for a full breakdown of those options:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals

Note that you can also use:

```
font.color.rgb = RGBColor.from_string("70ad47")
```

If that is more convenient for you.
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shared.html#docx.shared.RGBColor.from_string